# Send file to another application

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to send one file from my app to another. I don't want to use an "app chooser", I just want to "force" that app to open the file I want.

I've tried:

```
Uri data = Uri.fromFile( file );
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
Intent ic = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("org.ais.archidroid");
ic.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
ic.setData(data);
ic.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, data);
startActivity(ic);
```

But this just opens the other app without the file. I have tried several combinations and googled it and haven't found anything. Maybe it's not supported.

Comment: As the answers bellow show, when using another app you must know some implementation details, information that is usually in the Manifest file (launcher activity, supported actions). If you don't know this information, you can't use the third party app. Try asking the developers of the "Archdroid".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying ACTION_VIEW instead of ACTION_SEND. Something like this:

```
Uri data = Uri.fromFile( file );
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
Intent ic = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("org.ais.archidroid");
ic.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
ic.setData(data);
startActivity(ic);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting also the launcher activity of that app you seek:

```
Intent intent= new Intent("org.ais.archidroid.launcheractivity");
intent.setClassName("org.ais.archidroid", "launcheractivity");
intent.setData(Uri.parse(yourdata));
startActivity(intent);
```

But just make sure, you typed its packageName and className right... hope this will help.